# Conditionally Drag&Droppable/Reordable TreeView

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I have a problem with the setup of a Drag&Dropable Treeview in my UWP App with the ability, that users can reorder items within the tree. There is a demo application which i used to fit my needs. (https://github.com/chingucoding/TreeViewConditionalReorderSample)

Dragging and Dropping works like a charme, but, if i enable reordering, i'm unable to check the condition. Here a quick example:

```
- Group 1
-- Leaf 1.1
-- Leaf 1.2
-- Leaf 1.3
- Group 2
-- SubGroup 2.1
-- SubGroup 2.2
--- Leaf 2.2.1
- Group 3
```

So, the condition is always the same, the user is allowed to drop a leaf on every group, which has no childs OR just leafs wheras the user is allowed to drop groups just on Groups and just on groups with no childs OR groups with just group-childs.

Realworld: I want to display an "Table of Content" for a Cookbook, so the User is allowed to drop recipes on categories and group categories in a greater category. ;)

So, what is my exact Problem: Dragging and Dropping works like Charme, but if the user is allowed to reorder items in the tree, he will be able to sort "Leaf 1.1" between "Group 2.1" and "Group 2.2". I don't get any event to prevent that drop.

Comment: Could you share more detail about how do you sort the items?

Comment: TreeView Component has an abilitProperty to allow Reordering Items: CanReorderItems https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.treeview?view=winrt-18362

Comment: Yep， I know that property, it allow use drag and drop items when the value is true. And TreeView has `DragItemsCompleted`  `DragItemsStarting` event could use to detect which item moved.

Comment: no, there you have a second property for d&d actions: CanDragItems. I want to achive, that a user can drag a leaf between two existing leaves. Just Drag&Drop enabled doesnt allow the user to drop a leaf between. I HAVE TO activate the reorder property, but there i can't check my conditions, because a user can reorder over every depth inside the tree

Comment: Yep,You could record current treeview itemsoure  int `DragItemsStarting` and  check the `NewParentItem` of the drag item in `DragItemsCompleted` event , if the parent  is not correct please reload the TreeView itemsource with previous  itemsource .

Comment: I do. Dragging and Dropping works like a charme. I used the Sample Application i provided in my question. BUT this application takes care of Reordering Groups, which are juist allowed on root level. My Problem is, that my users can have Groups in Groups, maybe i can get al little demo project running.

Comment: Yep, please go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Derive from TreeViewItem, set AllowDrop = true, and set up a reference to the TreeView in your derived TreeViewItem (tvi). Test your conditions for dropping and reordering in the OnDragEnter, OnDragOver, OnDragLeave, and OnDrop overrides, defining local variables canReorder and canDrop. Then in each of the overrides, set tvi.TreeView.CanReorderItems = canReorder, and set args.AllowedOperation = (canDrop? args.DataView.RequestedOperation: DataPackageOperation.None). Then call the base function.

I recommend allowing reordering if the dragged items (which the TreeView's DragItemsStarting handler stored in args.DataView) can be dropped in the parent entity above the current entity (which is stored in tvi.DataContext).